# When should I use ScalableLinkProvider or ItemSearchLinkProvider?

Tags: link-manager, urls

I have noticed that the `Sitecore.Buckets.LinkProviders` namespace has 2 classes that extend the default `LinkProvider`: `ScalableLinkProvider` and `ItemSearchLinkProvider`. I cannot find any direct references to them in either code or config and I cannot find any documentation or blogs that mention them.

Can anyone tell me what the intended purpose of these classes is? Are there certain scenarios where I should use or derive from one of these link providers rather than the default `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ItemSearchLinkProvider

`ItemSearchLinkProvider` is a very simple provider with `GetItemUrl` method which:

1. Checks if item is inside a bucket
2. If no it returns `base.GetUrl` - where base class is `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider`
3. If yes, it generates url in a format:

```
return string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", 
    item.GetParentBucketItemOrSiteRoot().Name.ToLower(), 
    item.Statistics.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
    item.ID.Guid.ToString().Substring(0, 4), 
    item.Name.ToLowerInvariant());
```

So for example if your `My Last Article` item is insiade a bucket called `News`, was created on 17th of July 2018 and its id is `{360CB29F-4BF7-405C-916A-C1C4C2378902}`, the url will be:

```
"/news/2018-07-17/360c/my last article"
```

In my opinion, this format has no usage. I don't see any reference from the code or config to this class.

### ScalableLinkProvider

`ScalableLinkProvider` uses its own internal class `DatedLinkProvider` to generate url with format:

```
`/ancestors/up/to/site/root/itemname-201807171457`
```

where the numbers at the end are parent folders from the date and time in bucket structure in `yyyyMMddHHmm` format.

There is also a `ScalableLinkResolver` class which you could use to resolve the urls generated by `ScalableLinkProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, Marek. So the only reason I would use ScalableLinkProvider is if I prefer that URL format over the default?

Comment: I think so. The only difference is that instead of generating urls with `/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm` it adds `-yyyyMMddHHmm` at the end of the url. I'm not sure how it would work if your bucket is not under StartItem of your site. I've never used this provider on my own.